# <Maven> How is the command "mvn dependency:resolve" different from "mvn clean install"?

Tags: maven

I would like to ask about the use of the command "mvn dependency:resolve". When I executed the command in project folder, it seems it download jars and build the application. I wonder if it has the same functions as "mvn clean install". Thanks.

Comment: It does download jars—that's _resolving dependencies_. Why do you think that it "seems to build the application"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install will compile, test & package your Java project and even install/copy your built .jar/.war file into your local Maven repository.

But dependency:resolve compile your application and print resolved dependencies.